# Why the pointer to single integer memory location can't be deleted?

Tags: c++, dynamic-memory-allocation

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    int myarray [10];
    int * ptr1;
    ptr1 = new (nothrow) int [10];
    cout << "ptr1 = " << ptr1 << endl;
    delete [] ptr1;
    cout << "ptr1 = " << ptr1 << endl;

    int a = 4;
    int * ptr2;
    ptr2 = &a;
    cout << "ptr2 = " << ptr2 << endl;
    delete ptr2;
    cout << "ptr2 = " << ptr2 << endl;



    return 0;
}
```

It outputs

```
ptr1 = 0x9941008
ptr1 = 0x9941008
ptr2 = 0xbfca5cd4
```

Questions:

1) Why the second print of `ptr1` still return the same value? The memory is released but the pointer keeps the memory address value?

2) Why the second print of `ptr2` doesn't output?

Comment: As to the first, it just deallocates memory associated with ptr1, it doesn't mean it should change the value of ptr1 itself AFAICS

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- `delete` frees the memory, but does not change the value of the pointer. Note however, that the pointer now points to a deallocated area of memory so you should not use it until you reset it.
- Your program surely crashes before the second print since you're trying to free a pointer which has not been allocated on the heap. You can only `delete` areas of memory which you have previously allocated on the heap with the `new` operator.

Comment: It undefined behavoir to delete memory which wasn't allocated with new. A crash is one way this could look like. A crash somewhere down the line is another outcome. You would probably appreciate the crah the moment the undefined behavior happens but the reason it is undefined is that it may be expensive to detect. In this particular case the memory subsystem may now consider a piece of memory on the stack to be unused which will lead to interesting behavior at some point.

Comment: That's right. Given that the OP reported that the second time `ptr2` wasn't displayed, it is a reasonable guess that a crash occurred. It isn't impossible though, that some other outcome could have been observed.

Answer (score 2):

1) Because a pointer would still point to the same location. You are printing *where it points*, not *what it points to*. It's a description of where the program should find something. If you label a box, and then remove its content, the label (pointer) is still there.

2) You can't delete something that was allocated on the [stack](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/79-the-stack-and-the-heap/).

Answer (score 1):

Deleting a pointer doesn't change the pointer's value. It has essentially two effects:

1. it destroys the pointed to object. Obviously, destroying an int ha no effect
2. it announces that the pointed to memory is now unused to memory system

If you want to observe the intpointer being deleted you would need to replace the globel operator new() and operator delete() functions (which may be an interesting experiment but generally nothing you want to do in production code).